# Is it possible to get all table items from web to excel power query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

I need to get table data from a single page site and load them to excel power query so it can be easily refreshed.

The problem is that on site view, the table has a lot of items so it shows only the first 50 items and i need to click next to see the next set of items and so on. When i load the table in excel power query, it only gets the first 50 items. Is it possible for power query to get all items instead of the 50 items?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to include a link to the site you mention.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @FlexYourData. I am not allowed to share the link for it is an internal site.

Answer (score 0):

This is the limitation from the site, you can't solve it in Power Query.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'll try VBA macro instead. Thanks for the reply!